# Re-sizing Bootstrap Popover with JS - Multiple Popover Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have multiple bootstrap `popovers` and I'm trying to re-size them as needed with a JS.

Everything works if I have only one of these re-size functions and only the one clicked first will work. I tried to merge them, rename them with `ID` or `class` and nothing works for me.

my buttons

```
<a role="button"
   class="btn-default a"
    data-container="body"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-placement="left"
    id="a">Button A</a>

<a role="button"
   class="btn-default b"
    data-container="body"
    data-toggle="popover"
    data-placement="bottom"
    id="b">Button B</a>
```

Any way to have multiple of these alongside?

```
// button class a
var p = $('#a').popover();
    p.on("show.bs.popover", function(e) {
        p.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "300px");
    });

// button class b
var p = $('#b').popover();
    p.on("show.bs.popover", function(e) {
        p.data()["bs.popover"].$tip.css("max-width", "500px");
    });
```

BTW I have also tried to control the size of these `popovers` with `CSS` styles without any luck.

Comment: I think the problem might just be a simple JS mistake:  because you're using the same variable for both elements, inside the popover handler for button `'#a'`, `p` will refer to button `'#b'`.  Try assigning the two elements to different variables.

Comment: Well, as I said, that did the trick, now the second issue is that one of the buttons is used to update objects and the objects are loaded from remote url. The issue is that this button `b` will only work with one `class`. Any way to update the function with the `ID on the fly?